# Element width changes on scroll

Tags: jquery

If you open this site: http://www.pmfst.eu on mobile (max-width:360px) you'll notice the button for the menu on the top right. Once you click on it, it changes the width of the menu and the menu appears. This works as it should, but when you scroll (on a phone only) the menu disappears and I don't know why.

This is the jQuery function for the expandable menu:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function() {
    if(jQuery(".my_extra_menu_class").width() > 0){
        jQuery(".my_extra_menu_class").css('width', '0');
    }
    else{
        jQuery(".my_extra_menu_class").css('width', '300px');
    }
});
```

Please help?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: provide a demo fiddle, with working code.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita, I've found the error, but thanks for trying. If you're interested you can just access the whole siite on www.pmfst.eu. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error. Another JS function was changing the width of the menu and that's why it kept collapsing back. I've fixed it now. Sorry for this.